# How to loop for the min?

Tags: octave

```
for i = 1:n
        ymin = realmax;
        ymax = 0;
        for j = 1:4 % each perceptron
            for k = 1:40
                yval = waves0(k,j,i);
                if(yval > ymax) ymax = yval;
                if(yval < ymin) ymin = yval;
            end
        end
end
```

I'm trying to find the min and max value, yet when I run the function I get:

```
parse error near line 20 of file /Volumes/FDISK/mlr/YvalDistance.m

  syntax error



parse error near line 20 of file /Volumes/FDISK/mlr/YvalDistance.m

  syntax error



parse error near line 20 of file /Volumes/FDISK/mlr/YvalDistance.m

  syntax error



parse error near line 20 of file /Volumes/FDISK/mlr/YvalDistance.m

  syntax error
```

Line 20 is the last line of the function, and is empty.
If I comment `if(yval < ymin) ymin = yval;` I don't get the parse error anymore. What's up?

```
octave:39> version
ans = 3.2.4
```

Comment: You should close [if with endif](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-_003ccode_003eif_003c_002fcode_003e-Statement.html#The-_003ccode_003eif_003c_002fcode_003e-Statement) but you have 1k, this don't be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried closing your for loops with endfor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not get rid of your syntax error *and* speed up your code with:

```
yvals = zeros(1,4*40);
for j = 1:4
    for k = 1:40
        yvals((j*4)+k) = waves0(k,j,i);
    end
end
ymax = max(yvals);
ymin = min(yvals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
if (yval > ymax)
   ymax = yval;
else if (yval < ymin)
   ymin = yval;
endif
```

i am guessing it is because you never closed your if with an endif